# Creating release pipeline to several VMs

Tags: azure-devops, virtual-machine, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I have multiple ASP.NET web applications which I want to release into different VMs. Manually installing a DevOps agent in every single VM seems really inefficient. Is there a way to make this process faster? Is it possible to create release pipeline that could directly push the code to the public ip of the VM?

Comment: Hi @weewoo Did you get a chance to try out below answer? Please let me know how did it go? We can discuss it to work out a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, you can prepare scripts to register each new agent. Here you can find parameters: [Self-hosted Windows agents - Unattended config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#unattended-config).

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your web application with IIS deployment task, 
You can have a try using task **Manage IIS**, which can create website in a remote machine.
[image]

And then you can add a **Windows machine file copy** task to copy the build artifacts to the website Physical path in the remote machine.

Another workaround is that you can manage IIS with powershell script. So that you can add task **PowerShell on target machines** to run powershell script to manage IIS website. You can refer the example scripts at this [page](https://4sysops.com/archives/create-web-apps-and-application-pools-in-iis-with-powershell/), and [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools). For more information about IIS powrshell command you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools)